# How to programmatically obtain OAuth2 client credentials for Google API

Tags: oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to create a redistributable web application that will integrate with Google Analytics through the Google Reporting API. Customer will install the application on their server.

I'm following this tutorial (I'm using PHP, but I believe this is not of importance for my question)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api

This works fine. No issues there.

However I can't figure out one missing element:
The tutorial starts with sending me to the Google APIs console where I have to create and configure a new API project and create and configure a client ID.

That's a lot of work that requires fairly technical knowledge (redirect url, selecting correct API, error-prone copy-and-pasting, etc.)

So my questions:

- Is there an API so I can programmatically set this up for my user?
- If that's not possible, is there a more user-friendly way to obtain Analytics reporting that is future-proof? (I noticed they are currently deprecating a few older APIs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's AFAIK not possible.

You could go one of the following ways:

- Move `client_id` and `client_secret` to some configuration file and help your customer with deployment.
- Show a one-time setup wizard for your app and guide your customer step-by-step. There you can at least provide him with the right callback URLs.
- Regard your application as ["installed application"](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) and instrument [`curl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522869/how-do-i-use-oauth-with-php-and-curl) or something similar for sending the requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll probably go the "installed application" route. I hope I can capture the key through an iframe and make the experience as seamless as possible

Comment: A little follow up: I started experimenting with this "installed application" idea, but there are a few gotchas. oauth2 is not allowed in iframe. And even if you use a popup window, crossdomain policy restricts me from accessing the title (where the authorization code is)
On top of that: this would mean that all my users will go through my API access and would be restricted by my quota. This is unacceptable, so I will have to implement some kind of wizard/guide and will probably have to answer a ton of support mail :)