# OAuth1.0 with php and CURL not working

Tags: php, curl, oauth

- I am trying to hit api which is having OAuth1.0.
- Problem is when i am trying with Postman i am getting response but with PHP curl its giving error.
- In postman i am passing parameters as below

  url='xxxx', Authentication stuff is type=OAuth1.0,Consumer Key,Consumer Secret, Token, Token Secret, Timestamp, Nonce, Version=1.0, Realm=Optional
- Below is my code which i have tried

---

```
$url="xxx";
$header[]         = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,        true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode('Authorization:OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxx",oauth_token="xxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1475651061",oauth_nonce="LyA5sR",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="xxx"'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch))
{
echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
```

- I have added CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, because there was certification problem. Now i am getting 'Access denied'  from api curl error 403  because there is something wrong in the way i am passing for Oauth 1.0 by curl.
- This is the first time i am trying outh1.0 with curl. Please help me whats going on in my code. I have tried using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522869/how-do-i-use-oauth-with-php-and-curl)

Comment: I'm sure there's [a PHP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) to do this.

Comment: can u give me any example

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with oauth signature which is not getting formed properly. You can refer  https://oauth.net/core/1.0/ for more clarity